# having controlled and uncontrolled input fields in the same component is prevent the submission of form

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props, controlled-component

I have searched in all the answers provided on google for this question but still, I can not find out the solution myself.

I have a parent state that holds the bdate string and session array, those elements take their values from the input field and checkbox in the child component.
the scenario of my code is that I take the bdate and change the value in the parent state directly, then take the checked elements and put them in the child state array then after that pass the array as an argument to a function that assign the array to the session array in the parent component.

the problem is the input of the checkbox has a static value and the input of bdate has a dynamic value. this difference gives an error of 'A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled' and because of this error the validation function does count the bdate field as empty even if I entered some input in it

this more explanation in case anyone need more info:

I have a parent state that holds objects and one of these objects is an array called session, the session array should get its elements from the child components checkbox elements.
the scenario I followed generating my code is, I created a separate state in the child component, this state holds all the values of checked elements then I need to update the parent session array with the array in my child component. that is why I created a function in my parent component with a parameter that is then assigned to the session, I passed the function as props to the child components but whenever I call it, I get an error that 'A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled'!!! the thing is this error makes the browser count the input fields as empty and the validation gives an error that is why the form can not be submitted based on the condition in the useEffect.

I know it has something to do with the value attribute but i do not know how to fix it.

here is the code of my parent component

```
import react, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import AdminUser from './components/pages/adminUser';
import ProfileClient from './components/profileClient/profileC';

const App = () => {

  
  //client data
  const intialValuesClient = { bdate: "",session: [] };


  //client state
  const [clientValues, setClientValues] = useState(intialValuesClient);


  //client handlechange function
  const handleChangeClient = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setClientValues({ ...clientValues, [name]: value });
  }

//update the session array
  const setStateOfParent = (newSession) => {
    setClientValues({
      session: newSession
    });
  }



  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<AdminUser />} />
        <Route path='/profileclient' element={<profileClient data={clientValues} change={handleChangeClient} setSession={setStateOfParent} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )

}



export default App;
```

the child component code

```
import react, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



import './profileC.css';


const ProfileC = (props) => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const [profileErrors, setProfileErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
    const [sessionSelected, setSessionSelected] = useState([]);

//function to push the checked elements into the state
    const handleSession = (e) => {
        // Destructuring
        const { value, checked } = e.target;

        console.log(`${value} is ${checked}`);

        // Case 1 : The user checks the box
        if (checked) {
            setSessionSelected([...sessionSelected, value]);
        }

        // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
        else {
            setSessionSelected({
                sessionSelected: sessionSelected.filter((e) => e !== value)
            });
        }
    };



    const handleSubmit = (err) => {
        err.preventDefault();
        setProfileErrors(validate(props.data));
        setIsSubmit(true);

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(profileErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
            if (isSubmit) {
                return (navigate('/verifyc'))
            }
        }
    }, [profileErrors])

    const validate = (values) => {
        const errors = {};

        if (!values.bdate) {
            errors.bdate = 'bdate is required!';
        }
        return errors;
    }

    var show = true;

    const showCheckboxes = () => {
        var checkboxes =
            document.getElementById("checkBoxes");

        if (show) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            show = false;
        } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            show = true;
        }
    }

//here is where the error happens
    const handleClick = () => {
        // Simply call the setStateOfParent function from 
        // prop and pass required argument
        props.setSession(sessionSelected);
    }

    return (

        <div className="main">
            
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                        <div className="m_container">
                            <h1>Profile</h1>
<div className="m_birthday">
                                <input
                                    type="date"
                                    id="m_date"
                                    name="bdate"
                                    placeholder='Date of birth'
                                    value={props.data.bdate}
                                    onChange={props.change}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="multipleSelection">
                                <p className="selectBox" onClick={showCheckboxes}>What kind of session are you interested in?</p>
                                <div id="checkBoxes">
                                    <label htmlFor='Individual Session'>Individual Session</label>
                                    <input value='Individual Session' onChange={handleSession} onClick={handleClick} id='Individual Session' type="checkbox" name='session' />
                                    <label htmlFor='Couples Session'>Couples Session</label>
                                    <input value='Couple Session' onChange={handleSession} onClick={handleClick} id='Couples Session' type="checkbox" name='session' />
                                    <label htmlFor='Family Session'>FamilySession</label>
                                    <input value='Family Session' onChange={handleSession} onClick={handleClick} id='Family Session' type="checkbox" name='session' />
                                    <label htmlFor='Group Session'>Group Session</label>
                                    <input value='Group Session' onChange={handleSession} onClick={handleClick} id='Group Session' type="checkbox" name='session' />
                                    <label htmlFor='Work Pressure Session'>Work Pressure Session</label>
                                    <input value='Work Pressure Session' onChange={handleSession} onClick={handleClick} id='Work Pressure Session' type="checkbox" name='session' />
                                    <label htmlFor='Teen Session'>Teen Session</label>
                                    <input value='Teen Sesion' onChange={handleSession} onClick={handleClick} id='Teen Session' type="checkbox" name='session' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p className='errorMsg'>{profileErrors.session}</p>

                            <br />
                            
                            <div className="m_clearfix">
                                <button type="submit" className="m_start">Start Your Journy</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default ProfileC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array as an argument in case the user unchecks the box, try to change the `handleSession` function like this:

```
const handleSession = (e) => {
  // Destructuring
  const { value, checked } = e.target;

  console.log(`${value} is ${checked}`);

  // Case 1 : The user checks the box
  if (checked) {
    setSessionSelected([...sessionSelected, value]);
  }

  // Case 2  : The user unchecks the box
  else {
    // Change this condition
    const session = sessionSelected.filter((e) => e !== value);
    setSessionSelected(session);
  }
};
```